# IOS: Project crashing due to possibly using to much memory (Using ARC but might be due to image size)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

Hey all I am having some problems with my app. This is my first big project for the IOS and I have been doing pretty good so far some parts that troubled here and there. But now that development is basically over over I have the biggest problem and it has been troubling me for while and I have hit a wall. I am not sure what to do yet ( I have one idea but not sure if that will work).  On my computer it works most of the time. Sometime it
crashes and I get an error(see below). What I do when I get the error is usually the game is working and then all of a sudden just stop. I actually have not received the error in a while and I mostly got it when it was in development. 
When the app is ran on either my bosses machine or on the actual device (side note we upload the app from her machine to the device not from my machine), it crashes. It always crashes at the same point. The fist view, the title screen, appears. Then they click the start button and a new view is launched. However, they click the start button and the app ends up crashing. What happens is the app closes and the debugger goes to this part of the code.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MyAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Also, the app is a game. All the views use OpengelEs.
I am thinking what is happening is that to much memory is being used. The game is running; the system needs more memory and the system kills a process to release memory; the process being the app. This is based on what I know about the IOS and the application life cycle. I am using ARC but I have tested the game a lot specifically with their tools and I have not found any memory leaks or similar things that could cause the problem. I am thinking that the image might be to big file size wise. Images range from 100kb to 5 MB. We are having them sized down but I am not sure if that is the problem. Right now the only lead I have for why it is crashing is it is running out of memory and the only reason for that I have found is the file sizes. I am not 100% sure that this is the cause because it does not explain why it does not crash (at least not recently) on my machine but it does on her(it explains why it does for her machine and the device and it explains why it sometimes happen on mine but not that they happen under different conditions). Also I have always heard that some type of low memory warning should occur under conditions when this happen. Can someone confirm deny this (I have researched this but have not found a lot

So what I am asking is if anyone might have any more suggestions on the cause of this problem or at least lead me into topics that I should research more. Do you think lowering the file size of the images would work. There tends to be 1 background that is about 1-3 and then anywhere from 8 to 40 images that are 100kb.

**EDIT**
I used the profile mode instruments. The app started using 100mb and then while playing it went up to 500mb (this is in real memory). I noticed that it only went up memory when I switched to a new level. I figured it was because each level had more images display but then I did a test. In the test instead of going to the next level when a level is finish level one is played again. 
Each level is an object of Class Level. My ViewControler (which is a subclass of GLKViewController) has an property called currentLevel. The game switches to the next level with the following code:

```
-(void) nextLevel: (Level) newLevel
{
    //play sound
    MyAppDelage *del=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIWindow *main=[delegate window];
    MyViewControler *view=(MyViewControler*) main.rootViewController;
    view.currentLevel=newLevel;
 }
```

So what I think is happening is that the old level never gets garbage collected for some reason; currentLevel is strong if that makes any different.
Also I had 
@synthesize currentLevel =_currentLevel;
This is really old code that I wrote when I was first learning Objective C. I was just following examples at time. Would possibly changing either strong type or removing the @synthesize  part would help this problem?
I am use to more C++/C#/Java syntax so I am really not use to some of objective C styles yet.

Comment: try testing the app in profiling mode within Xcode. You can see how much memory it uses (and other nifty stuff).

Comment: The point is, figure out whether it's the memory issue that's causing it to crash. It could be something else (like a bug that causes a crash). The tool to use within Xcode is called Instruments. Check out the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) on that.

Comment: Thank you guys. I edited the question after using the advice you gave me  and I am a bit closer to solving it.

Comment: @user1189789: how is `view.currentLevel` defined?

Comment: the synthesize is not the issue, just trying to save you time going down that road.

Comment: @Isaac 
In the view controller class (in the header file)
"@property" (strong) Level* currentLevel;

Comment: If you're running out of storage your app delegate will be sent a warning message (applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:).  Implement that method and put a breakpoint/log there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing any of your code I suggest to check the following:

1. Check if the images you use have small pixel dimensions, since Apple advices that images which have width/height larger than 1024 pixels SHOULD better be split into tiles. Look for example at Apple's PhotoScroller.app code. Note that although an image may be small in size (say 100 kb), in order to display it iOS needs to decode it using 4 bytes per pixel! Thus an image of 3000x3000 pixels uses 3000x3000*4=36,000,000 bytes equalling about 34 MB of memory.
2. Although you are using ARC, look at for/while loops in your code which may handle images and surround (where applicable) the image handling code with @autoreleasepool { .. }. For example:

   ```
   for (NSString *imageName in imageNames) {
       @autoreleasepool {
           //... code here to get your images for display ...
       }
   }
   ```
3. Look critically in how you handle retrieving a lot of images, i.e. iOS caches images fetched using 'imageNamed' versus 'imageWithContentsOfFile'. This technique is especially used in handling large images using CATiledLayers. The following code fragment show the two flavors of getting an image:

   ```
   // The fetched image is cached by iOS when using:
   UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimagename.png"];
   // You can control memory usage and freeing of the image when using:
   UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"myPath/myimagename.png
   ```
4. You may also look at the code used in the LargeImageDownsizing example from Apple, but note that this didn't work for me when handling PNG files. I submitted a bug-report (last year November) to Apple but haven't heard anything yet.
5. Finally don't wait too long with testing on a real device, since your development Mac is at least 10 times faster than the target iDevice and has also a whopping more memory available before you start to notice memory related issues. It is by the way always a good habit by using the Instruments.app for profiling your app.

Hope the above suggestions may help you! Just my 2 (Euro)cents, for what its worth yet.

Comment: You where spot on. Thank you so much. I had no idea that images where 4 byte/pixel

Comment: Glad to be of any help! I've also been struggling quite a lot with PNG images which seemed very small. Especially that on Android-OS, developers can use a specific byte encoding which seems to use 1 byte per pixel instead of the 4 bytes in iOS.